# Há uma maneira mais correta de tratar redirecionamentos em fluxos de autenticação? (ex: HTTP Status 302, ou JavaScript, ou formulário com auto-submit)

Tags: node.js, session, autenticação, redirect

Trabalho em um projeto onde temos uma aplicação Frontend e uma segunda aplicação Backend (NodeJS) que cuida da autenticação e contém uma API REST. Na parte de autenticação, o Backend gera um token de sessão e salva em um cookie no browser do usuário. Até aí tudo bem.

Agora que temos o cookie de sessão salvo, precisamos redirecionar o usuário para a URL inicial no Frontend. A dúvida é: existe uma prática de mercado da melhor ou mais correta forma de fazer isso (em termos de segurança, principalmente)? Temos as opções abaixo:

1. retornar um HTML com refresh meta tag;

```js
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.status(200).send(`
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL='https://www.redirect-url.com/'"/>
   </head>
</html>
`);
```

2. retornar um HTML que contem um script que altera o `window.location.href` pra URL de redirect;

```js
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.status(200).send(`
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         window.location.href = "https://www.redirect-url.com"
      </script>
   </head>
</html>
`);
```

3. retornar um HTML que contém um formulário com atributo `action` configurado para a URL de redirect e que é feito autosubmit dele ao carregar a página por meio do atributo `onload`;

```js
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.status(200).send(`
<html>
   <body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
      <form method="post" action="https://www.redirect-url.com">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
`);
```

4. configurar HTTP Status 302 (Redirect - Found) e header Location na resposta para que o Browser redirecione o usuário;

```js
res.redirect('https://www.redirect-url.com');

// ou então...
res.set('Location', 'https://www.redirect-url.com');
res.status(302).end();
```

Então, ignorando a questão do SEO e olhando da perspectiva de segurança, padrão de mercado e suporte de browsers, há uma maneira mais correta de fazer isso?

Comment: `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` não é um erro "global", é provavelmente devido a algum erro do lado do servidor (podendo ser infra) ou erro em algum  header que passou no momento de um redirecionamento, o que você deve fazer  **[edit]** e adicionar **um [mcve] do problema**, com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva o que precisa. **Não delete e não repita a pergunta**, basta editar e aguardar o processo de reabertura. A reabertura (isso se sua pergunta estiver OK depois do editar) será avaliada por 5 usuários aleatórios na "fila de analises". Siga as dicas. Obrigado.

Comment: Acredito que isso seja uma pergunta baseada em opinão. Mas, eu utilizaria os cabeçalhos (ou seja a 4ª opção). Ela também é a única que funcionaria sem suporte para JS, ou seja caso você faça um requisição fora do navegador.

Comment: Existe algum motivo específico para você querer que o servidor seja responsável por redirecionar o usuário? Por que não fazer o frontend cuidar disso? De qualquer forma, dentre as opções listadas, eu acredito que a 4ª seja a melhor. Contudo, reitero que o front-end lidar com conteúdo de front-end (redirecionamento, a página que seu browser está acessando, nesse contexto) é, na minha opinião, a prática mais sensata.